# Access framebuffers from compute shaders

Tags: graphics, rust, shader, vulkan, compute-shader

I have a compute shader which renders an image. The image is basically a finished frame.

I would like to render said image on the screen. The most obvious way to do this is to instead of rendering to this image, rendering straight to the frambuffer. I have been told however, that this requires the `storage` bit to be set on the framebuffer, which is not the case on my machine.

The next best thing is then to copy over the image to the framebuffer. This requires the `target` bit to be set on the framebuffer image, which luckily happens to be the case on my machine.

However, when I try to copy into the framebuffer, Vulkan gives an access error, saying the framebuffer is not initialised.

```
AccessError {
    error: ImageNotInitialized { requested: PresentSrc },
    command_name: "vkCmdCopyImage",
    command_param: "destination", command_offset: 4
}
```

If it matters, I am using the [Rust bindings](http://vulkano.rs/) to Vulkan. The code is quite bulky, the entire thing is available on [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/binero/wingrendering/tree/master). The command buffer is created as follows:

```
let command_buffer = AutoCommandBufferBuilder::new(queue.device().clone(), queue.family())?
    .clear_color_image(image.clone(), ClearValue::Float([1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]))?
    .dispatch(
    [(WIDTH / 16) as u32, (HEIGHT / 16) as u32, 1],
    compute_pipeline.clone(),
    set.clone(),
    (),
    )?
    .copy_image(
    image.clone(),
    [0, 0, 0],
    0,
    0,
    render_manager.images[next_image_index].clone(),
    [0, 0, 0],
    0,
    0,
    [WIDTH as u32, HEIGHT as u32, 1],
    1,
    )?
    .build()?;
```

*I know I could just render to a quad on the image, which is what I am doing now, but it's a lot of bulky code that doesn't do much.*

Comment: "*However, when I try to copy into the framebuffer, Vulkan gives an access error, saying the framebuffer is not initialised.*" How could we know what would cause that without seeing your code? Like, *all of it*?

Comment: Also exact error message.

Comment: @NicolBolas I thought I no longer had the original code (I moved to rendering a quad now), but I do happen to have the original code still! I will amend it to the answer shortly.

Comment: That error must be coming from the Rust bindings, not from Vulkan itself, so I'm guessing a bit. But it sounds like it's complaining that you're copying to an image that is still in PRESENT_SRC layout. After acquiring a swapchain image, you need to transition it from PRESENT_SRC to an appropriate layout (GENERAL or TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL in this case), fill it, and then transition it back to PRESENT_SRC before presenting.

Answer (score 2):

The [doc](https://docs.rs/vulkano/0.9.0/vulkano/sync/enum.AccessError.html#variant.ImageNotInitialized) says about `ImageNotInitialized`:

> Trying to use an image without transitionning it from the "undefined" or "preinitialized" layouts first.